# Xcode 8.2 simulator showing white screen and giving SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

I'm new to app development and I'm learning as I go. I started a new project and set the image background via image view and a png. Before preceding with anything else, I wanted to make sure that at least my background would show in the simulator.

When I run the simulator it shows a white background for a few seconds then Xcode pops up in AppDelegate with a

> [4904:767382] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DataViewController''
>    First throw call stack:
>   `

[image: Error]

[image: Simulator]

[image: Background]

Can anyone explain what the problem maybe?

Comment: Can you post the output that gets printed to the console?

Comment: Look at the bottom of your screen shots. See the error message? Expand that debug console. Copy and paste that complete error and put into your question (as text, not as a picture).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Storybaord ID ( DataViewController ) to your view controller in storybaord

a line like this may cause the crash

```
   let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DataViewController")

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: The Background file is a .png.  All the imported assets are in the assets folder within the project.  As far as constraints, i set it to auto-scale.  Is that what you mean by constraints?

Comment: yes , i mean layout constraints in the image field it must be Background.png but any way paste the console log of the crash

Comment: 'self.dataLabel!.text = dataObject

Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXEC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0'

Comment: I think,  I'm going to delete everything and just start over.  This is just my background and i shouldn't be experiencing issues this early on for something that, imo, should be so simple